# Possible jQuery.delay Bug?

Tags: jquery, debugging, accordion, delay, fade

I'm using jQuery.delay in tandem with jQuery.accordion and jQuery.fadeIn/Out effects.  Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").load("update.php");
    var refresh = setInterval(function() {
      $("#accordion").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#accordion").load("update.php", function() {
          $("#accordion").delay(1);
          $("#accordion").fadeIn("slow");
        });
      });
    }, 5000);
  });
</script>
```

What this does is load HTML generated by update.php in an accordion layout (i.e it's collapsible content), and every 5 seconds it will poll update.php for new HTML and fade it in after fading out the old HTML.

The problem arises at the line reading `$("#accordion").delay(1);`. With this line in, the section of content that's collapsible gets curtailed somehow and won't "unfurl" like a proper accordion effect should. All the data is still there; you can click and drag your mouse to scroll down through it. It just doesn't render properly in the browser or draw the div correctly or something. By simply removing that line, it loads successfully and without issue.

I encourage you to try reproducing my results, and let me know if you can locate a work-around, because I really do need that delay in there! Thank you for reading.

Comment: You know that `delay(1)` is 1 millisecond, right? Is that what you're intending to accomplish? Does the same thing happen if you try `delay(1000)`?

Comment: Yes, the 1ms is just there for proof-of-concept. It doesn't matter what you set it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all things, I am an idiot.  It turns out the makers of jQuery knew of this issue all along and programmed in autoHeight and clearStyles to fix the issue.  If anyone else is encountering a similar div truncation error with their AJAX'd accordion effect, you will want to use one of these parameters to rectify it.  It had to do with the way delay() interacted with fade() effects to create 0 height elements. autoHeight resets the height of them to your tallest element, and clearStyles resets them entirely on an event.

Answer (score 2):

delay() is no replacement for setTimeout(). It delayes running animations, but there is no animation running(fadeOut should already be finished there)

Comment: Nope, nevermind.  It has the exact same truncation error as delay().  Anyone else wanna take a crack at it?

Comment: You can replicate this problem by downloading the latest jQuery UI and using their default accordion demo.  Just move the HTML contents to a separate PHP file (i.e. update.php) and call it via the method described above. Any time you use a delay() or setTimeout in conjunction with a setInterval to auto-refresh, it will return empty divs (though the accordion effect remains).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delay the fade, your code should read:

```
          $("#accordion").delay(1).fadeIn("slow");
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/Vf97G/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this is the exact same as placing it on a line above the fadeIn. delay() works by delaying the next animation in the queue. It results in the very same truncation error.